# Correctly making a threaded FTP download (Indy/Android)

Tags: android, delphi, ftp, indy, delphi-10.1-berlin

I've made an IdFTP to download files from my FTP server, however when I try to make it Threaded it stuck in "Resolving hostname..." in Android OS.

Without Thread (working fine):

```
uses ..., IdFTPCommon;

var
  RecordDownload: TMemoryStream;

uses System.IOUtils;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdFTP1.Host := 'motoristaajudante.ddns.net';
  IdFTP1.Port := 2121;
  IdFTP1.DataPortMin := 50100;
  IdFTP1.DataPortMax := 51100;
  IdFTP1.Username := 'anonymous';
  IdFTP1.TransferType := IdFTPCommon.TIdFTPTransferType.ftBinary;
  IdFTP1.Passive := True;
  try
    IdFTP1.Connect();
    IdFTP1.Get('00001.m4a',TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + '00001.m4a',True,False);
  except
    IdFTP1.Disconnect;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdFTP1AfterGet(ASender: TObject; AStream: TStream);
begin
  IdFTP1.Disconnect;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdFTP1WorkEnd(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode);
begin
  if FileExists(TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + '00001.m4a') then
  begin
      ShowMessage('Downloaded!');
  end;
end;
```

And the Threaded code I made following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20688839/correctly-using-taniindicator-in-firemonkey-mobile-dev-for-wait-for-processing) :

```
uses ..., IdFTPCommon;

type
  TLoadThread = class(TThread)
  public
    constructor Create; reintroduce;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
  ...
  procedure ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);

var
  RecordDownload: TMemoryStream;
  Loading: Boolean = False;
  zLThread: TLoadThread = nil;

uses System.IOUtils;

constructor TLoadThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TLoadThread.Execute;
begin
try
  Form1.IdFTP1.Connect();
  Form1.IdFTP1.Get('00001.m4a',TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + '00001.m4a',True,False);
except
  Form1.IdFTP1.Disconnect;
end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  zLThread := nil;
  Loading := False;
  FloatAnimation1.Enabled := False;
  FloatAnimation2.Enabled := False;
  Arc3.StartAngle := -90;
  Arc3.EndAngle := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdFTP1.Host := 'motoristaajudante.ddns.net';
  IdFTP1.Port := 2121;
  IdFTP1.DataPortMin := 50100;
  IdFTP1.DataPortMax := 51100;
  IdFTP1.Username := 'anonymous';
  IdFTP1.TransferType := IdFTPCommon.TIdFTPTransferType.ftBinary;
  IdFTP1.Passive := True;
  zLThread := TLoadThread.Create;
  zLThread.OnTerminate := ThreadTerminated;
  zLThread.Start;
  Loading := True;
  FloatAnimation1.Enabled := True;
  FloatAnimation2.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdFTP1AfterGet(ASender: TObject; AStream: TStream);
begin
  IdFTP1.Disconnect;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdFTP1WorkEnd(ASender: TObject; AWorkMode: TWorkMode);
begin
  Form1.FloatAnimation1.Enabled := False;
  Form1.FloatAnimation2.Enabled := False;
  Form1.Arc3.StartAngle := -90;
  Form1.Arc3.EndAngle := 0;
  if FileExists(TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + '00001.m4a') then
  begin
      ShowMessage('Downloaded!');
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdFTP1Status(ASender: TObject; const AStatus: TIdStatus;
  const AStatusText: string);
begin
  Memo1.Lines.Add(AStatusText);
  Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

Then the FTP status show it stuck in "Resolving hostname ...". How to make it correctly threaded?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no reason to use the `OnAfterGet` and `OnWorkEnd` events the way you are using them. Indy is synchronous. `TIdFTP.Get()` does not return until the transfer is finished, and if an error occurs then an exception is raised.

So, get rid of both event handlers, use `try/finally` instead of `try/except` to call `Disconnect()`, and process the download only if `Get()` does not raise.

The `OnWorkEnd` and `OnStatus` events are triggered in the context of the same thread that calls `Connect()`, `Disconnect()`, and `Get()`. So, in your threaded example, that would be the worker thread, not the main thread. But your event handlers are not synchronizing access to your UI controls. That can cause all kinds of problems, including the freeze you are experiencing. You *must* synchronize (the `TThread.OnTerminated` event is synchronized).

With that said, try this instead:

Non-threaded:

```
uses
  ..., IdFTPCommon;

...

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdFTP1.Host := 'motoristaajudante.ddns.net';
  IdFTP1.Port := 2121;
  IdFTP1.DataPortMin := 50100;
  IdFTP1.DataPortMax := 51100;
  IdFTP1.Username := 'anonymous';
  IdFTP1.TransferType := IdFTPCommon.TIdFTPTransferType.ftBinary;
  IdFTP1.Passive := True;
  try
    IdFTP1.Connect;
    try
      IdFTP1.Get('00001.m4a', TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + '00001.m4a', True, False);
    finally
      IdFTP1.Disconnect;
    end;
    ShowMessage('Downloaded!');
  except
    ShowMessage('Error while downloading!');
  end;
end;
```

Threaded:

```
uses
  ..., IdFTPCommon;

type
  TLoadThread = class(TThread)
  public
    constructor Create; reintroduce;
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  end;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    ...
    IdFTP1: TIdFTP;
    procedure ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
    ... 
  private
    Loading: Boolean;
    zLThread: TLoadThread;
  end;

...

constructor TLoadThread.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(True);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TLoadThread.Execute;
begin
  Form1.IdFTP1.Connect;
  try
    Form1.IdFTP1.Get('00001.m4a', TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + '00001.m4a', True, False);
  finally
    Form1.IdFTP1.Disconnect;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.ThreadTerminated(Sender: TObject);
begin
  zLThread := nil;
  Loading := False;
  FloatAnimation1.Enabled := False;
  FloatAnimation2.Enabled := False;
  Arc3.StartAngle := -90;
  Arc3.EndAngle := 0;
  If TThread(Sender).FatalException = nil then
    ShowMessage('Downloaded!')
  else
    ShowMessage('Error while Downloading!');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  IdFTP1.Host := 'motoristaajudante.ddns.net';
  IdFTP1.Port := 2121;
  IdFTP1.DataPortMin := 50100;
  IdFTP1.DataPortMax := 51100;
  IdFTP1.Username := 'anonymous';
  IdFTP1.TransferType := IdFTPCommon.TIdFTPTransferType.ftBinary;
  IdFTP1.Passive := True;
  zLThread := TLoadThread.Create;
  zLThread.OnTerminate := ThreadTerminated;
  zLThread.Start;
  Loading := True;
  FloatAnimation1.Enabled := True;
  FloatAnimation2.Enabled := True;
end;

procedure TForm1.IdFTP1Status(ASender: TObject; const AStatus: TIdStatus; const AStatusText: string);
begin
  TThread.Queue(nil, 
    procedure
    begin
      Memo1.Lines.Add(AStatusText);
    end
  );
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Remy, it's working perfectly and plus give me a way to handle download errors.